# Can I visit the Great Wall of China from Beijing on a 72 hour visa?

Tags: visas, china, transit-visas, beijing, great-wall-of-china

With regards to the Chinese 72-hour visa, [this](https://www.travelchinaguide.com/embassy/visa/free-72hour/) states "Passengers transiting in Beijing, Chongqing, Harbin, Guilin, Kunming, Wuhan, Xiamen, or Tianjin cannot leave the administrative area of the transit city."

I am unclear if any section of the Great Wall is in the administrative area of Beijing. If so, which sections are in the Beijing administrative area?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes the Great Wall passes through Beijing Adminstrative District. You could likely find a tour that takes you up to Huairou to see the Great Wall and Museum.